# using jQuery forEach to find the <p> on which the original click happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a list of `<p>` where some clicks may originate. I understand how to scroll through them with something like this:

```
        $('p').each(function() { 

        });
```

But what I don't understand is how to get the values of some items inside those paragraphs.  I am looking at the API here for attributes: http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/ but somehow I see not much relevant stuff.

Here is a typical contents of my `<p>`

```
<p class="half_text">0 
    <strong>
      <a class="vote_up" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#" data-problem_id="48">Vote Up</a>
    </strong> 
    | 0 
    <strong>
        <a class="vote_down" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#" data-problem_id="48">Vote Down</a>
    </strong>
</p>
```

What I need to do is increment or decrement the 0 that is inside the "half_text" or right after the | character in the middle of the whole thing.  I can wrap them inside the span tag, but how do I match up the span tag with the data-problem_id="48" part of that particular `<p>`?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you should track your clicks by tracking the click events themselves.

Comment: @Maxx what do you mean?  Srry, not good with the jQuery lingo yet.

Comment: I meant that you could use click events like what gion_13 suggested. Justin Niessner's answer does appear to be more concise though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use an each loop at all. If you're handling the click even on the links, you could do something like:

```
var $this = $(this);
var p = $this.parentsUntil('p');
if($this.hasClass('vote_up')){
    $this.text(parseInt($this.text, 10) + 1);
}
else {
    $this.text(parseInt($this.text, 10) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you wrap your values into spans for a simpler reading :

```
<p class="half_text">
    <span class="votes_up">
        0 
    </span>
    <strong>
      <a class="vote_up" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#" data-problem_id="48">Vote Up</a>
    </strong> 
    |  
    <span class="votes_down">
        0 
    </span>
    <strong>
        <a class="vote_down" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#" data-problem_id="48">Vote Down</a>
    </strong>
</p>
```

And then, the script is more simple and more easy to read :

```
$('p.half_text a.vote_up').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var votes = $(this).closest('span.votes_up');
    votes.text((+votes.text() || 0) + 1);
});
$('p.half_text a.vote_down').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var votes = $(this).closest('span.votes_down');
    votes.text((+votes.text() || 0) + 1);
});
```

Comment: The span with the value is not a sibling of the link.  It needs to be `$(this).parent().siblings('span.votes_up');`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.vote_up').click(function(event) {
  var span = $(event.target).parent().find('.yourSpanClass');
  span.html(parseInt(span.html())+1);
};
```

I will leave for you doing the same thing for vote_down.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after http://jsfiddle.net/7T4AK/

I added `spans` so you can easily access the number that needs to incremented.
This should get you on the right track to figuring out how to do the same for the down vote.

```
$('a.vote_up').click(function(){
    var span = $(this).closest('p').find('span.up');
    span.text(parseInt(span.text(),10) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').click(function(e){
    alert( $(e.target).html() );
});
```

work on from here..

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your numbers in `<span>` tags, and then you can do something like this:

```
$('a', 'p.half_text').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), $p = $this.closest('p.half_text'), $num, chg = 1;
    if($this.hasClass('vote_up')) {
        $num = $p.find('span.up');
    }
    else if($this.hasClass('vote_down')) {
        $num = $p.find('span.down');
        chg = -1;
    }
    $num.text(parseInt($num.text(), 10) + chg);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gRLad/7/